# LoadImageW returns null c++ win32

Tags: c++, winapi

I started making a simple c++ Win32 program. I was simply trying to load an Image into a window, but it didn't really work. I was debugging for some time, and I know that the problem is that my LoadImageW() function returns null. Code:

```
void loadImages() {
  hPic1 = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(NULL, L"pic.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
  if (hPic1== NULL) {
      MessageBox(NULL, L"Error", L"LoadImage error", MB_OK);
  }
}
```

The .bmp file is in the same directory with the .cpp file, and I even tried with the whole path but it didn't work. I get no errors and the main window loads correctly, but the image doesn't display and the message box appears. The loadImages() function gets called at WM_CREATE of the window. The SendMessageW() function looks like this:

```
SendMessageW(hImageWindow, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hPic1);
```

Any help is appreciated, and have a nice day!

Comment: What's the error code?

Comment: [The documentation says to call GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagew).  What is the value of `GetLastError()`?  Also, do **not** call `MessageBox` before calling `GetLastError` -- the `GetLastError` call should be done immediately after determining that `hPic1` is NULL.

Comment: The error is (translated from my language) something like "Task Completed Successfully"

Comment: *"The .bmp file is in the same directory with the .cpp file"* - This is of no consequence. Once the compiler is done producing object code, information on the whereabouts of the source file is lost. That said, sound code will always use fully qualified path names. If the function fails with a fully qualified path name, it's reasonable to assume an invalid file. To solve this, open the file in MS Paint and save it again. That'll produce a valid BMP file.

Comment: @IInspectable I did that, now I get no error and the image loads successfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After calling LoadImageW or any win api function that leads to unexpected result! check documentation in MADN especially "Remarks" section!
Based on documentation may be it is good to call GetLastError()! By checking error code you find the problem, such as "file not found", access privilege error and etc.

You can find description of each error code returned by GetLastError() in page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes or check by visual studio IDE in Tools-> Error lookup menu!

Comment: You have to be careful not to do this for functions whose documentation doesn't say to.

Comment: You also have to be careful to only call `GetLastError` under the conditions explicitly spelled out in the documentation, exactly at the correct time, and no later. The latter seems to be particularly troublesome with C++ developers.